# Using Serializable attribute with base class only in class declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, xml-serialization, object-serialization

I have a class which uses object serializer to serialize properties. The class is derived from another class as follows

```
[Serializable]
public class TargetInfo:
    PropertyHandler
```

When I call the serialize method, serializer tries to serialize the PropertyHandler class as well and throws different exceptions since PropertyHandler class does not comply to the Serialization rules. How can I avoid serialization of PropertyHandler and serialize only TargetInfo?

Comment: If you are using XmlSerializer you don't need `Serializable` attribute.

Comment: Removing the Serializable attribute makes no differnce. Still getting the same exception messages. If I dont inherit from TargetInfo, then I dont get the error messages, but I cant live without inheriting from TargetInfo.

Comment: How about posting self-contained simple code showing your problem? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options... if you want to serialize a class that extends a base class, then that base class *must* also be marked with the `Serializable` attribute. You can however add the`NonSerialized` attribute to members of the base class that you do *not* want to be serialized.

If this is *still* not right for you, you can try some custom serialization by implementing the `ISerializable` interface, providing you with more control over exactly what is serialized. Please take a look at the [Object Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) page at MSDN for more help on this subject.